# How to use map method in rails views

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a restaurant that has_many menus and a menu that has_many sub_menus. Am trying to get the total orders for each menu or sub_menu within rails views. I already have the logic of splitting the two (menu and sub_menu) through if, else statement. But am having trouble of having sum of all orders for each menu or sub_menu. I have tried this

```
<% restaurant.menus.each do |menu| %>
    <%= menu.orders.map{|sum, order|sum+order %>
<% end %>
```

this throws an symbol '+' error while this gets count but not total

```
<%= restaurant.menus.orders.count %>
```

UPDATE

---

A restaurant has_many menus (model Menu) while a menu has_many sub_menus (Model sub_menu). Both menu and sub_menu have many orders (model Order). So am trying to get count of orders a menu or sub_menu has. Hope its quite clear.

Comment: what is 'order'? a field in menu and submenu?

Comment: ur second statement to display orders count is incorrect since orders relation ship will work only on menu and not menus since the later is an array. pls define the relationships in the question more briefly

Comment: made an update to question above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u can make the below changes to get the count of menu orders and sub menu orders for a restaurant

```
Restaurant 
  has_many :menus
  has_many :sub_menus #u can add this if it doesnt exist
  has_many :menu_orders, :through => :menus, :class_name => "Order" #this will give u an array of orders for all the menus of the restaurant
  has_many :sub_menu_orders, :through => :sub_menus, :class_name => "Order" #this will give array of orders for all the submenus of the restaurant

Menu
  belongs_to :restaurant
  has_many :sub_menus
  has_many :orders

SubMenu
  belongs_to :restaurant #u can add this if it doesnt exist
  belongs_to :menu
  has_many :orders

Order
  belongs_to :menu
  belongs_to :sub_menu
```

Answer (score 0):

The method `map` iterates over all the orders of the given menu, yielding a single order object everytime. This object is stored in `sum` because it is the first variable in the block-local list you have provided `|sum, order|`. Since nothing more is yielded, `order` variable will be nil for each iteration.
Now as you can well imagine, no `+` method is defined on your order model class. Hence it throws a `undefined method`+' for ` exception.

If this seems strange, then always remember that writing `a+b` is just a short-form of writing `a.+(b)` where `+` is a method of `a`.

The following may be helpful:

```
sum=0;
menu.orders.map{|order| sum+=order.price}
```

I assumed there was a `price` field in your `order` model. Hope this helps. And btw, you have a missing `}` in the code. Did you see it?

Comment: let me try and add it to my class model.

Comment: If you have not added it beforehand, where was the actual price amount of the order was being stored?

Comment: it was being stored as total_amount within order model while price is in menu model

Comment: Ok if you want to sum the `total_amount` of all orders, just replace `price` with `total_amount` in the code in my answer

Comment: Sorry u must have misunderstood. Needed the total count of orders made from both main menu and sub_menu. More like prasad solution. problem is db is too big at the moment